# Mysql : How accurate is the output of explain statement for rows field?

Tags: mysql

I have indexed tow columns namely (client_id,batch_id).

I then use explain keyword to check if select stament is using index or not and found that it is using index named as "client_id_batch_id".

```
mysql> explain  select count(*) from authentication_codes where client_id=6 and batch_id = "74" \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: authentication_codes
         type: ref
possible_keys: client_id_batch_id
          key: client_id_batch_id
      key_len: 773
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1915982
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

But in my authentication_codes table there are only 1 million rows for client_id=6 and batch_id=74 combination then why rows filed shows 191 598 rows? I was expecting it to show 1 million records.

Answer (score 1):

As per the mysql [document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html), it means that how many rows were examined for your statement. so it was around 191K rows (not necessarily only the rows that satisfies the condition) that were examined to fetch output for you.